# Why is my React component mounting after each action?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have a React component called `Home` which is calling an action to fetch some groups when the component mounts.

I am calling an action as follows:

```
componentDidMount() {
    const { fetchRecentGroups } = this.props;
    fetchRecentGroups();
}
```

My reducer is picking up each action perfectly fine and is returning a state as follows:

```
switch(action.type) {
    case REQUEST_GROUPS:
        return {
            ...state,
            loadState: FETCHING
        };
    case REQUEST_GROUPS_SUCCESS:
        return {
            ...state,
            loadState: SUCCESS,
            groups: action.data.groups,
            totalResults: action.data.totalResults
        };
    default:
        return state;
}
```

I am also using the `connect` HOC on this component as follows:

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {}
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    fetchRecentGroups: () => {
      dispatch(actions.fetchRecentGroups())
    }
  }
}

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(Home);
```

The `Home` component is placed inside a `Route` like this:

```
<Route 
    exact={true} 
    path="/" 
    component={Home} 
/>
```

My problem is that each time the reducer returns a state, the `componentDidMount` is called again and again in a loop. I would expect the mount to happen only once at the first load.

If I put `componentDidUpdate` and `componentWillReceiveProps` functions in my component, they are never called (only `componentDidMount`) so I am not able to compare props.

Does anyone know why this may be happening?

**EDIT:**

I have found my problem to be caused by this piece of code in my route:

```
const RouteBlock = () => {
  if(errorSettings) {
    return <Error {...errorSettings} />
  }
  return (
    <div className={styles.RouteBlock}>
      <Route exact={true} path="/" component={Home} />
      <Route path="/search" render={() => <div>SEARCH</div>} />
    </div>
  );
};

return <Router><RouteBlock /></Router>
```

I changed it to:

```
return <Router>{RouteBlock()}</Router>
```

Comment: would you mind to post the all Home class?

Comment: I'd guess there's some SFC up the component tree that rerenders on that action so the whole subtree is invalidated and a new instance of Home component needs to be created which triggers the same process over and over again.

Answer (score 1):

Every time you render your component, you are immediately calling function that is setting new state and you are triggering re-rendering of your component. Maybe you should use shouldComponentUpdate life cycle method that will check is your old state the same as new one.

Check out official docs: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#shouldcomponentupdate